# Wordpress Multisite - API posts return an empty array

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I try to use wordpress configured as multisite. The `/posts` url return posts fine except one site.

From one site (site_id:2) where posts is actually exists the `/posts` api endpoint returns an empty array.

Another endpoints like `/media` and `/comments` returns json with data which refers to some posts by id. But endponts like `/posts/{id}` where `id` is actually posts returns error json with error:

> {"code":"rest_post_invalid_id","message":"Invalid post ID.","data":{"status":404}}

When I call `get_current_site()` at the place where above error is fired it return same data for all the sites (for all urls which is associated to each site), however for (site_id: 1 or 3) as mentioned above list of posts generated by rest api is not empty, problem only with `/posts` for site id:2.

What are possible to check?

Is any palce in wp where I can intercept all sql queries?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept WordPress SQL queries using the following:

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
```

Another example is

```
$customPosts = new WP_Query($yourArgs);
echo "Last SQL-Query: {$customPosts->request}";
```

Another method would be to utilize this functions.php file code at the link below.

[Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612)

Comment: I do not found any hook to intercept queries. (First of your line is actually empty and secod seems does not intercepts the posts queries). I dump or just return query directly from wordpress `get_posts` function.

Answer (score 0):

I dump or just return query directly from wordpress `get_posts` function. And the query appears actually worked and return the post by id.

But after returning the post from `get_posts` the function `get_post` of `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` class check that its field `post_type` is equal `post_type` of returned post. And if it is not equal it fires a mentioned in question error.

The error does not actually describe a problem. Actually the post type is not equal to post type of controller.

Actually post type of posts was not a `post` but `page`.

So need to switch to use rest endpoint from `/posts` to `/pages`.